# Error getting inserting dats into table

Tags: sql-server, create-table

I have created two tables as below and inserted data according to table structure.

```
create table table1(
customerID int identity Primary key,
customerName nvarchar(30))

create table table2(
sensorID int identity Primary key,
location nvarchar(20) not null,
temp decimal not null,
custID int
foreign key(custID) references table1 (customerID))

Insert into table1 values(1000,'john smith')
Insert into table1 values(1001,'Mike Coles')
Insert into table1 values(1002,'sam carter')

Insert into table2 values(1000,'NY',70,1001)
Insert into table2 values(1001,'NY',70,1002)
Insert into table2 values(1002,'LA',60,1001)
Insert into table2 values(1003,'CA',67,1000)
Insert into table2 values(1004,'NY',70,1002)
```

But while executing I am getting the below error messages

Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'table1' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Can someone please answer why I am getting these errors.

Comment: Exactly what the error message tells you.

Comment: Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'table1' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'table1' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.
Msg 8101, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
An explicit value for the identity column in table 'table1' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set IDENTITY INSERT to ON

   `SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 ON`
2. Make a column list for your insert like instead of inserting directly without specifying the columns

   ```
   INSERT INTO TABLE1(CUSTOMERNAME) SELECT 'john smith'
   ```
3. Turn off the Identity Insert

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass values for `customerID` for `table1` because its identity is `ON`. it will be auto incremented.

first insert into `table1`:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table1 OFF
Insert into table1(customerName) values('john smith')
Insert into table1(customerName) values('Mike Coles')
Insert into table1(customerName) values('sam carter')
```

then let's do insert into `table2`

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table2 OFF
Insert into table2(location, temp, custID) values('NY',70,1)
Insert into table2(location, temp, custID) values('NY',70,2)
Insert into table2(location, temp, custID) values('LA',60,1)
Insert into table2(location, temp, custID) values('CA',67,1)
Insert into table2(location, temp, custID) values('NY',70,1)
```

**NOTE:** You need to first insert records to `table1` then on successfully and then only you will be able to insert into `table2` just because you have set `Foreign Key` that references `table1's customerID`.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I created another table named table11,executed and table11 created and make explicit insertion with SET IDENTITY_INSERT table11 ON with the above data...then SET IDENTITY_INSERT table11 OFF. when executed got the same error  message.

Comment: What I did I removed identity from customerID from table11 and inserted the above values and executed.Then did the same for table22. while executinf insert statements got the below eror: Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Insert Error: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
5 such errors...

Comment: which query you are using for `table22`?

Comment: I just created another table22 which was previously my table2 and put these data as suggested by you:            
Insert into table2 values(1000,'NY',70,1001)
Insert into table2 values(1001,'NY',70,1002)
Insert into table2 values(1002,'LA',60,1001)
Insert into table2 values(1003,'CA',67,1000)
Insert into table2 values(1004,'NY',70,1002)

Comment: Use table1 and table2  database table schema's as in your question and then execute query as per my updated answer. And please don't pass values to identity columns as i said its auto incremented and leave it to sql to insert values in that columns.